# Node.js - can't use jQuery after installing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I installed jQuery for Node with the line:

```
npm install jquery
```

In the beginning of my server-side Node.js code, I put this:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

It installed fine and the module is visible on my server. Now, I'm trying to do this in that same file:

```
$.each(rows, function(num, row){
            console.log(row.username);
        });
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object function ( w ) {
                                if ( !w.document ) {
                                        throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                                }
                                return factory( w );
                        } has no method 'each'
    at Query._callback (/home/lights/public_html/apps/node_servers/fircik_gamelist.js:69:5)
```

It says it 'has no method each' which I don't understand because, obviously, jQuery should have that method. Before I installed the jQuery module, I tried to run the same code and it gave the error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, and that error is no longer present after installation completed successfully.

So what am I missing here?

What does it mean when it says 'jQuery requires a window with a document'?

Comment: And this is probably in windows, right ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve overall? That is, *why* are you trying to use jQuery in Node?

Comment: No, it's a Linux/Apache server. I just want to make my code cleaner, in this case being able to  use `$.each` would make my life easier and my code more readable.

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery), you'll need a DOM to work with jQuery, so you have to create one with something like jsdom.

Comment: Would you say this is a better choice than avoiding jQuery and just using plain Javascript for my server-side coding?

Comment: You really don't need jQuery if that's all you're going to do. Native JavaScript arrays have `.forEach()`, `.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.filter()`, and more. [Documentation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_of_array_instances)

Comment: I've never used jQuery in Node, I just don't see the need? There's no DOM, and as it's serverside you generally don't need a DOM. If you're including jQuery just to do iteration, array and objects stuff etc. I would avoid it, there are methods included in V8 for just about anything that jQuery does anyway.

Comment: Best alternative is [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org)

Comment: @thefourtheye - No, the best alternative is plain javascript, and Node supports all the newest stuff, so libraries are generally not needed.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll just stick with plain Javascript. There will be other stuff I'll want to do besides array manipulation, but nothing too problematic so jQuery doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @adeneo It not only has these functions but also many helper functions necessary for functional programming. And they also use native implementations if they are available.

Comment: Well, in Node they are always available, so browser inconsistency is not an issue, and most of what the current DOM libraries bring to the table is just overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is a library created for clientside javascript (javascript that runs in a web browser). Javascript that runs in a webbrowser has a `window` and a `document` object. Javascript that runs on the server (Node.js) doesn't have that (because it doesn't have a `window` or `document` of course..).

So that might be the reason jQuery doesn't work on the server side.

You can also do loop through the elements of an array with native javascript:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    console.log(rows[i].username);
}
```

Or (as Pointy pointed out) with the native [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function on the Array prototype:

```
rows.forEach(function(row) {
    console.log(row.username);
});
```

Comment: Or with the native `.forEach()` function on the Array prototype.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense to me. What is the use of having a jQuery module for Node.js if it can't be used server-side? I mean, if I want to use it client-side then I'll just include it on the page. Thanks for pointing to the alternative code for looping through arrays.

Comment: Ok, I understand now based on the discussion in the comments to my question.